# WCF (401) Unauthorized When Referencing Dll

Tags: c#, wcf, vb6

I have to shoe horn a call to a WCF service into a legacy VB6 app.  To do this, I'm referencing a c# dll to call the wcf method.  In the dll I'm setting the configuration as opposed to using a config file.  The dll works when I run my unit tests, but once I execute it within the vb6 app, I get the following error:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest. WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout) The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM,Basic realm=[the ip]

The service is using basic authentication.  In both scenarios I'm using the same url, username, and password.  Here is the configuration I'm doing in code:

```
    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding
{
    SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
    OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
    CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
    ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
    AllowCookies = false,
    BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
    HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard,
    MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Mtom,
    TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
    TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered,
    UseDefaultWebProxy = true,
};

binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;

var wcf = new [servicename](binding, new EndpointAddress([the url]));

if (wcf .ChannelFactory.Credentials != null)
{                
    wcf .ChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = [the username];
    wcf .ChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = [the pw];
}
```

I can't figure out what is different when it gets executed by the VB6 app.  Any input is appreciated.

Comment: What credentials is the VB6 app running under?

Comment: Further to Tim's question.  Is the VB6 app running as a service?  Is it a COM component or running in COM+/Component services?  Is it started by another application?

Comment: Try enabling tracing on your service and inspect the trace log for the message header to find the username/password that is being passed when you invoke it from your unit tests and when invoked from your VB6 app. That should tell you why you get a 401 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C# DLL is registered for com interop.  I had assumed it was a byproduct of being called through vb6, but I took at step back and realized the wcf credentials were being provided correctly by the vb6, but the code path it followed in the dll was slightly different and they weren't being applied correctly.

Always seems to be that when things make no sense at all, some underlying assumption is wrong.  Thanks for the suggestions.